# XML bulk update in Evenote

Tags: rss, xml, evernote, twitter, wordpress

I've some tweets and blog article (from Wordpress) saved locally in rss or xml format and I want to bulk upload them in my Evernote Account.

I've tried this [Wordpress to Evernot script](https://github.com/adammorris/Luis-Rei-Wordpress-to-Evernote/) or tried ifttt without success. Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks a lot for your help!